# Get all my Woocommerce product IDs in an array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, discount

I try to get all my product ids in an array which I can use to choose 4 random products every day.

There is my function, but something does not work... It's probably a problem with wc_get_products, but I don't really understand the problem.

```
function periodic_discount_prices( $price, $product, $parent = 0 ){
    // Get all the product Ids in an array
    $ids = wc_get_products( array( 'return' => 'ids', 'limit' => -1 ) );
    // Set the product Ids that will be discounted
    $discounted_products = array_rand( $ids, 4 );

    if( get_discount_period_rate() && in_array( $product->get_id(), $discounted_products ) ){
        $price = $product->get_regular_price() * get_discount_period_rate();
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you get any error? How do you know 'something does not work'?

Comment: 4 of my products should be on sale, but nothing happens on my website...